# The difference among "type of", "sort of", "kind of" and "style of" when referring to categories

Tags: meaning, word-usage

This video (https://youtu.be/4kuhQzbc2Tw) says "type of", "sort of", "kind of" and "style of" are all the same when referring to categories.

```
What type of music do you like?
What kind of music do you like?
What sort of music do you like?
What style of music do you like?
```

All of them is to talk about the favorite category.

I got some other sense about this, "type of" would be used in some more formal cases, such as written English; while "sort of", "kind of" would be used in some less formal cases; all of them mean some categories.

The following sentence sounds normal.

```
Adverbs are a type of words that describe verbs adjectives other adverbs or clauses.
Adverbs are a sort of words that describe verbs adjectives other adverbs or clauses.
Adverbs are a kind of words that describe verbs adjectives other adverbs or clauses.
```

While this one
    Adverbs are a style of words that describe verbs adjectives other adverbs or clauses.

seems a little bit strange,

As for "style", this one

```
jazz is a style of music
```

is more idiomatic, though this one

```
jazz is a genre of music
```

seems better.

Is my understanding above correct?

Comment: To me 'a sort of restaurant' suggests an establishment that serves food but isn't exactly a restaurant. Anyway since KFC is a commercial franchise, wouldn't you describe it as a 'chain of restaurants'?

Comment: Your understanding here is pretty good. We are talking about *idiomatic preference* rather than rules so it’s hard to be definitive. Any statement about what is “most appropriate” can fall over in another context or even in a different English language idiolect. Some people would often see KFC as a particular *example* of a restaurant not a type/sort/kind/style: *“A fast food outlet is a type of restaurant and the KFC and MacDonald’s chains offer good examples.”*  (In *traditional* Australian usage a fast food *shop* was not even considered to be a “restaurant”.)