# Singular or plural: "Adverbs are a type of words" or "Adverb is a type of words"

Tags: grammar

singular or plural:

I used this example in a post ([The difference among "type of", "sort of", "kind of" and "style of" when referring to categories](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/237937/95044))

> Adverbs are a type of words that describe verbs adjectives other adverbs or clauses.

Where I'm not sure which is supposed to be used, singular or plural. I guess each of them makes sense.

with singular

> Adverb is a type of words that describe verbs adjectives other adverbs or clauses.

refers to any/each adverb;

with plural, it refers to all types of adverbs.

Is my understanding right?

Comment: "Adverbs are a type of word".

Comment: @BillJ Thanks! Would you please explain a little bit?

Comment: a type is singular. Plural is: Adverbs are types of words that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your understanding that the difference has to do with *any/each adverb* as opposed to *all types of adverbs* is incorrect. The sense in both is plural.

There is some confusion among native English-speakers over which is correct, and it might be safest to rephrase your sentence to avoid 'type of' altogether.

'An adverb is a word that describes . . .'
'Adverbs are words that describe . . .'

What do you gain from telling us "An adverb is a *type of* word"?

There is considerable discussion of this on StackExchange. Here, for example:

[Types of things vs. types of thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/types-of-things-vs-types-of-thing)

There are some useful rules suggested there. In general it seems that in the UK we prefer 'types of thing' and in the US they prefer 'types of things'.